# BSD script command prevents a terminal from recognizing its size. How can I fix this?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, bsd

I’m using `script` command to record a terminal log all the time. It’s a useful command, but a terminal size isn’t reflected when I change it because of this command.

Let’s say I change a terminal size without using `script` command.

Before I change it, `stty` command, which confirms or reflects a terminal size, shows as follow.

```sh
$ stty size
53 200
```

Then, I will change a terminal size.

```sh
$ stty size
35 158
```

You will see my terminal size has changed.

Next, I will change a terminal size with using `script` command.

Before I change it, `stty` command shows as follow.

```sh
$ stty size
53 200
```

Then, I will change a terminal size.

```sh
$ stty size
53 200
```

`stty` command doesn’t recognize my actual terminal size when using `script` command.

This causes the appearance of some command is broken, such as `less` or `vim`.

I know `stty` command has ability to reflect a terminal size as follow.

```sh
$ stty rows <ROWS> cols <COLS>
```

But I’m too lazy to execute this command above every time I change a terminal size.

Originally, `stty` command should recognize terminal size changes automatically. But `script` command does something bad I think.

How can I fix this problem? Or could you please let me know the alternative?

Here’s my environment:

- script command BSD December 4, 2013
- macOS Big Sur 11.4
- iTerm2 Build 3.4.8
- zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)

I haven’t tried GNU version of `script` command yet, but it seems that GNU version of it can’t be installed on a Mac computer.

I have tried on Terminal.app as well, but the same problem occurred.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `script` works by creating a fake terminal. Hence, it's a layer between your terminal and your shell, so if it doesn't correctly implement this logic, there you go.

Comment: Anyhow -- how about installing a separate piece of software that does a better job of creating a fake terminal, and _also_ can keep logs? `tmux` is an excellent tool for the job.

Comment: ...or, of course, you can just use a terminal emulator with built-in logging support. iTerm 2 has such support, so I don't know why you'd need to run `screen` on top of it.

Comment: BTW, [apple.se] is a better place for questions about MacOS-specific tools, or [unix.se] for UNIX tools in general. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_, and arguably this doesn't qualify.

Comment: I think running GUI oriented programs (like vi or less) within `script` is a bad idea anyway: You'll find a *lot* of escape sequences in the typescript then. Script was never intended for that, except maybe you want a very fast reproduction of your editor session ;-) Likewise script was never intended for changing terminal sizes, but maybe it could be changed to handle it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not to forget "SuperUser"...